# Windows Universal Contacts capability name invalid

Tags: win-universal-app, appxmanifest

I am trying to add the contacts capability (described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx) to my Windows Universal App. I am adding it as shown below in my `Package.appxmanifest`:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <Capability Name="contacts"/>
</Capabilities>
```

However i get `The 'Name' attribute is invalid` in Visual Studio 2015 editor. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contacts capability is provided through the `uap/windows10` namespace and used as:

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">

  ...

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="contacts"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```